# ClearOS as domain controller

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-controller, clearos

I'm attempting to use ClearOS as my Domain Controller for a Windows network with no success.

When attempting to join the domain I get this fun error:

```
An error occurred when DNS was queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used to locate a domain controller for domain su.dc.

The error was: "No records found for given DNS query." (error code 0x0000251D DNS_INFO_NO_RECORDS)

The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.su.dc
```

But when I do an nslookup on _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.su.dc I get the address of the ClearOS box.

I'm using WinXP Pro to test with.

The domain is su.dc.

ClearOS is running:
     DNS and DHCP

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing an nslookup will by default look for A records.  The error says that it is looking for an SRV record.  You'll need to ensure that all the SRV records are there.

If you need domain controllers why not use Windows servers which were made to be domain controllers.

Comment: +1 for everything, but mostly for "Use Windows". Everything else sucks pretty badly at being a DC. Windows rocks at it. Why miss out on goodies like group policy and multi-master replication?

Comment: Personally I've never understood the whole, lets make something else be a Windows domain controller.  In the long run that really can't be cheaper than a few hundred bucks for a Windows license.

Comment: A few hundred bucks is more then I want to pay for plaything. ;)

Comment: Much as I hate Windows, the logic of using Windows to do a Windows job is undeniable. It really comes down to nothing more than using the most appropriate tool for the job.

Comment: @John Although your logic seems sound,  I have used ClearOS as a domain controller on a handful small networks and find it is a very decent, low-cost/low maintenance alternative to what M$ offers.